# Gulp-inject not ignoring path

Tags: laravel, gulp, gulp-inject

I'm trying to add gulp-inject into my Laravel codebase, and i need my styles files to be injected with the path `/styles/b/app.min.css` this, because Laravel compiles it's Blade Views into HTML files on it's own, so i have to make any gulp changes in the Blade View and not the compiled view...

The problem is that whenever i run my task and it tries to inject the file it injects it as follows

```
<!-- inject:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles/app.min.css">
<!-- endinject -->
```

Which obviously breaks on the actual view, because when i browse to the page it's already in the public directory, the public directory is the webroot of my project, so it's trying to find app.min.css inside of `public/public`

I need to ignore any references to `public/` and as such i've tried using `ignorePath` as follows

```
return gulp.src(config.paths.viewsDirectory + argv.version + '/index.blade.php')
    .pipe(inject(stylesStream), { ignorePath: ['public/'] })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.viewsDirectory + argv.version))
```

The documentation isn't very specific as to what this does exactly but i assume it's meant to remove the 'public/' string from my path before injecting it, but it's not doing that... regardless of that option being set or not the path returned in the view is always the same...

What can i do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, instead of using gulp.src inside of my inject() i was sending in the stream from my styles task, this adds another problem because now the injection takes place before the styles task is finished but that's another issue, essentially the solution is that ignorePath won't work unless you're using gulp.src